# NetBeans 8.2 Tool Bar Icons are too Small

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, icons, size, toolbar

I am running NetBeans 8.2 with an Asus q325 2in1 with windows 10. I recently installed jdk 9 and netbeans looked fine, but it would not create a projects. I decided to uninstall jdk 9 and install jdk 1.8. Now I can use the IDE, but the icons and entire interface is much smaller. I don't know how changing my jdk could cause the icons in the compiler to show up smaller. I unchecked the 'Small toolbar' option and they are still too small. I also increased the font size.

Comment: Attaching a picture may be useful.

Comment: Unchecking **Small Toolbar Icons** and increasing the font size are the normal solutions for this issue, but you have already done all that. As NiVeR suggests, could you update your post with a screen shot showing the toolbar problem? Also, have you tried changing screen resolution?